# Asymptotic behavior of parametric equations?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, parametric

I apologize if the answer to my question is already on the Internet somewhere, but if it is, I couldn't find it, nor can I prove it myself.

The question is a short one: given a suitably "nice" parametric function 
$$
T(t) = (x(t), y(t))
$$ 
if we have the asymptotic relationships
$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) &\sim w(t)  &(\text{as } t \rightarrow t_0)\\
y(t) &\sim z(t)  &(\text{as } t \rightarrow t_0)\\
\end{align*}
$$ 
and we define
$$
U(t) = (w(t),z(t))
$$
then does this imply that 
$$
T(t) \sim U(t) \ (\text{as } t \rightarrow t_0)
$$
where $t_0$ $\in \mathbb{R}\ \cup \ \{-\infty, \infty\}$? I imagine so, as the $x$ and $y$ components are both asymptotic, so it would seem that the overall functions should be asymptotic too, but I don't know how to prove such a thing. For all functions I have tested this relation is true, but I don't know how I might go about proving such a thing. Furthermore, if there is a proof for this relation, is there a good criteria for where this type of relation might fail?

Comment: how is defined your equivalence relation $T(t)\sim U(t)$ ? Does it mean components are equivalent to each others ? If so I don't see the problem